# Add/set Department name to contact

Tags: google-apps-script, contacts

How to add or set value for "Department" field in google contacts?
No problems with "Company" and "Job title"

```
var contact = ContactsApp.createContact('John', 'Doe', 'john.doe@example.com');
var company_set = contact.addCompany('Google', 'Product Manager');
// ?????
var department_set = contact.add______________('IT');
```

UPD: Thanks to @TheMaster I've managed to solve this task. 
Nice API example you can find here https://www.any-api.com/googleapis_com/people/docs/people/people_people_createContact
Using the examle on this site you can build required body for API.

```
  var reqBody = { 
    names: [
      { 
        givenName: givenName, 
        familyName: familyName 
      }
    ],
    phoneNumbers: phoneNumbers,
    organizations: [
      {
        title: orgTitle,
        department: orgDepartment
      }
    ],
    emailAddresses: [
      {
        value: emailAddres,
        type: 'work'
      }
    ],
    addresses: [
      {
        city: city,
        streetAddress: streetAddress,
        type: 'work'
      }
    ],
    memberships:  [
      {

        contactGroupMembership: {
          contactGroupId: contactGroupsID,
          contactGroupResourceName: "contactGroups/" + contactGroupsID
        }
      }
    ]
  }

createContact(reqBody);
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation?

Comment: @TheAddonDepot, thanx for your comment. Here is the list of Fields and ExtendedField  [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts) But I can't find "Department" there. The only solution I see is to add custom field named "Department". But it is just workaround, not a solution.

Comment: If a "Department" field isn't supported then adding a custom field is your only option.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot, I can't find field "City" in the documentation as well. But this field could be populated by setting the address like .setAddress('123 Main St, Raleigh, NC, 27601');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set `department` through People API with [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people). When a contact is [created through the api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact),  the people object can include `organizations[].department`

Comment: thank you! I've managed to create new contact using Peopple API.